# ¿Cómo calcular frecuencias de aparición de los valores de una columna?

Tags: r, count, frecuencia

Necesito una función similar a `count` pero que en lugar de mostrarme el número de veces que aparece un valor en mi `data.frame`, me muestre el % de cada valor con respecto al total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma más tradicional en R base para contar frecuencias es [`table()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/table):

```
table(mtcars$cyl)

 4  6  8 
11  7 14
```

Sin embargo, si lo que buscas es el procentaje, las salida anterior la pasas por [`prop.table()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/prop.table):

```
prop.table(table(mtcars$cyl))

      4       6       8 
0.34375 0.21875 0.43750
```

Ahora, si trabajas con `dplyr/tidyverse` puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(prop = n / sum(n))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
    cyl     n  prop
  <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1     4    11 0.344
2     6     7 0.219
3     8    14 0.438
```